Spring @ConfigurationProperties and Prototype Scope Behavior
I'm working with Spring Boot and I have a class annotated with @ConfigurationProperties to bind external configuration properties. By default, when the application starts, Spring creates a singleton instance of this class, and this same instance is returned for each request, which is expected behavior.
However, when I try to change the scope of this class to prototype by adding @Scope("prototype") and changed some property in the application.yml file and resend my request, I noticed that it doesn't create a new instance for each request as I expected. Instead, it still returns the same instance because that changed property is the same as before.
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "isoft")
@Getter
@Setter
@Validated
@RefreshScope
public class DataBaseConfigDTO {
    //The final keyword is avoided to allow the bean states to change
    private Map<String, String> datasource;
    private List<String> maintainers;
    private String manager;

    //for triming manager
    public DataBaseConfigDTO(Map<String, String> datasource,
                             List<String> maintainers,
                             String manager) {
        this(datasource, maintainers, manager.trim(), false);
    }

    private DataBaseConfigDTO(Map<String, String> datasource,
                              List<String> maintainers,
                              @Email String manager,
                              boolean idle) {
        this.datasource = datasource;
        this.maintainers = maintainers;
        this.manager = manager;
    }
}


application.yml file:
isoft:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: cards.oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:testCards
    username: 'AMz.cards__'
    password: '123.cards.'
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 10000
  maintainers:
    - shahsavariCards
    - mohammadiCards
  manager: iot@micro.cards

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"

Controller:
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/loans", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
@AllArgsConstructor
@Validated
    public class LoansController {
        private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
private final Environment environment;
    
 @GetMapping("/props")
    public ResponseEntity<DataBaseConfigDTO> getProps() {
return ResponseEntity.ok((DataBaseConfigDTO) applicationContext.getBean("isoft-com.isoft.accounts.dto.DataBaseConfigDTO"));

    }
}

when I change some property in application.yml witch is placed in github repo and I call the /refresh from actuator and then call the /api/v1/loans/props ,it returns the last value of that property and it does not sync with the latest value but when I change my approach and use environment#getProperty it work fine and returns the latest value of that property.

Actually/according to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reloading-properties#reloading-config-prop it should be working like that... Possible sources of error/confusion: the access to config props, (location of) the props file itself, user/"beta" error,... Please add details on: how you access the config properties, how you test...

@xerx593 I added some extra explanation

Facts to consider: 1. "rest controller" is (as any bean) singleton by default. 2. we use auto wiring with constructor injection and a final variable... Effectively: dataBaseConfigDTO field and its values won't "ever" change... https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/factory-scopes.html#beans-factory-scopes-sing-prot-interaction offers explanation and solution approaches to this "problem" ;)

I tried to do this without depending on the controller and using the  dataBaseConfigDTO with the applicationContext.I did like this in the controller: applicationContext.getBean("isoft-com.isoft.accounts.dto.DataBaseConfigDTO") and I also added the @RefreshScope on this bean and when the github properties are changed I called /refresh of this service and everything went well. the environment#getProperty returned the last value of this changed property but the property has not changed!I also changed my code.

Dont use @ConfigurationProperties to reload properties, its not made for that. its designed for one time read and then cache results. Also it reads from the jar not from the repo or file system. For reloading use a custom class to load properties using json with a mapper and reload it everytime by a call to an API

Prototype scopes don't resolve the fresh configuration each time you need to call /refresh for that to work. The BeanDefinition belonging to the prototype scoped bean will not get updated without the refresh, but it will be used to create a fresh instance each time. So without a call to refresh the underlying BeanDefinition will simply not refresh.

I don't know why, but when I put @NoArgsConstructor on my class, it works fine! I also tested it with only @RefreshScope and not @NoArgsConstructor(meaning having a constructor othre than the default one that has no args), and it did not work! meaning that we should have a no-args constructor to see the updated version of the bean. I was really surprised about this. Can someone help with this?
dto updated version:
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "isoft")
@Getter
@Validated
@Setter //required for refreshing
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DataBaseConfigDTO {
    //The final keyword is avoided to allow the bean states to change
    private Map<String, String> datasource;
    private List<String> maintainers;
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private String manager;

    public void setManager(String manager) {
        this.manager = manager.trim();
    }
}


@M. Deinum please see this.
